# Undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass When Implementing Stripe Connect

Tags: stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-6

I attempting to implement Stripe Connect in my Rails 6 app.
I can successfully redirect the User to Stripe on-boarding.

I'm using the `omniauth-stripe-connect gem`

I'm getting `undefined method` update_attributes' for nil:NilClass`for the`if @user.update_attributes({` line

The error that I'm getting is after the `User` has completed `Stripe On-boarding` I redirect them to my application. Below is my `OmniauthCallbacksController`:

```
class PetProviders::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  # You should also create an action method in this controller like this:
  # def twitter
  # end

  def stripe_connect
    auth_data = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    @user = current_pet_provider
    if @user.update_attributes({
      provider_name: auth_data.provider,
      uid: auth_data.uid,
      access_code: auth_data.credentials.token,
      publishable_key: auth_data.info.stripe_publishable_key,
    })
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Stripe Account Created and Connected" if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.stripe_connect_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  # More info at:
  # https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#omniauth

  # GET|POST /resource/auth/twitter
  # def passthru
  #   super
  # end

  # GET|POST /users/auth/twitter/callback
  # def failure
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # The path used when OmniAuth fails
  # def after_omniauth_failure_path_for(scope)
  #   super(scope)
  # end
end
```

I suspect that `current_pet_provider` is empty!

How do I get `current_pet_provider` within `OmniauthCallbacksController` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to retrieve the @user from Omniauth before you can use it?  https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth#integrating-omniauth-into-your-application

Comment: Hello @floatingLomas thanks for the response. I made some adjustments but this was helpful to get it working.
I can now successfully update the user.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code snippet below, I first obtain the user using the `email` and then I insert the new data that I want.

```
data = auth_data.info
@user = PetProvider.find_by(email: data["email"])
```

With everything put together, my `stripe_connect` method now looks like so;

```
def stripe_connect
    auth_data = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    data = auth_data.info
    @user = PetProvider.find_by(email: data["email"])
   
    if @user
      @user.provider_name = auth_data.provider
      @user.uid = auth_data.uid
      @user.access_code = auth_data.credentials.token
      @user.publishable_key = auth_data.info.stripe_publishable_key
      @user.save!

      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:notice] = "Stripe Account Created and Connected" if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.stripe_connect_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      flash[:error] = "Unable to Connect To Stripe"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

Comment: Why did you accept your own answer when my answer pointed you to the solution?